# glGetActiveUniform reports uniform exists, but glGetUniformLocation returns -1

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a vertex shader that for some reason I can't get the location of one of the uniforms.

I use `glGetActiveUniform`to get all the uniforms available, and my uniform is there (`bones[0]`).

However, when I call `glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram_, "bones[0]");`, it returns -1.

I also tried `glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram_, "bones");`, but it also returns -1.

Here's the shader:

```
#version 330 core

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 pvmMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

layout (std140) uniform Bones
{
    mat4 bones[100];
};

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 color;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 normal;
layout (location = 3) in vec2 textureCoordinate;
layout (location = 4) in ivec4 boneIds;
layout (location = 5) in vec4 boneWeights;

out vec4 ourColor;
out vec2 texCoord;
out vec3 normalDirection;

void main()
{
    mat4 bones2[100];
    for(int i=0;i<100;++i)
    {
        bones2[i] = mat4(1.0);
    }

    // Calculate the transformation on the vertex position based on the bone weightings
    mat4 boneTransform = bones2[ boneIds[0] ] * boneWeights[0];
    boneTransform     += bones2[ boneIds[1] ] * boneWeights[1];
    boneTransform     += bones2[ boneIds[2] ] * boneWeights[2];
    boneTransform     += bones2[ boneIds[3] ] * boneWeights[3];

    //mat4 tempM = mat4(1.0);
    //boneTransform = tempM;

    // This is for animating the model
    vec4 tempPosition = boneTransform * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = pvmMatrix * tempPosition;

    float sum = boneWeights[0] + boneWeights[1] + boneWeights[2] + boneWeights[3];
    if (sum > 1.01f)
        gl_Position = pvmMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    else if (sum < 0.99f)
        gl_Position = pvmMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

    /*
    if (boneIds[0] > 99 || boneIds[0] < 0)
        gl_Position = pvmMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    else if (boneIds[1] > 99 || boneIds[1] < 0)
        gl_Position = pvmMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    else if (boneIds[2] > 99 || boneIds[2] < 0)
        gl_Position = pvmMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    else if (boneIds[3] > 99 || boneIds[3] < 0)
        gl_Position = pvmMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    */
    // Calculate normal
    vec4 normalDirTemp = boneTransform * vec4(normal, 0.0);
    normalDirection = normalize(normalMatrix * normalDirTemp.xyz);

    //gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
    //gl_Position = pvmMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    ourColor = color;
    texCoord = textureCoordinate;

    for(int i=0;i<100;++i)
    {
        if (bones[1] == mat4(0.0))
            ourColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
}
```

I also tried using `uniform mat4 bones[100];` in my shader, which *did* give me the uniform location (0), however, all of the data was `mat4(0.0)`, even though I'm pushing data to the uniform.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uniforms in a uniform block do not *have* locations. You set their values by [binding a buffer object](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object#OpenGL_Usage) to the appropriate binding index for that block. This is the entire point of putting uniforms in [interface blocks](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Interface_Block_%28GLSL%29).

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense!  Thanks @NicolBolas.  I changed my shader to use `layout (std140, binding = 0) uniform Bones`, which has everything working now (can see my animation).  Oddly, `uniform mat4 bones;` still doesn't work if I use the `glGetUniformLocation` and `glBindBufferBase` functions.  Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

In OpenGL you can't get the position of a particular array index directly. Instead, you should do `glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram_, "bones");`. This will give you the location of the first element of the array. If you want to access another elements, like bones[1] or bones[20], you have to add the desired index number to the value returned by glGetUniformLocation.

So, the location of bones[0] is retrieved using `glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram_, "bones");` , the location of bones[1] is retrieved using `glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram_, "bones") + 1;` , and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Ivelate, didn't know that.  Unfortunately, that didn't work either (I edited my question to reflect that).